# Listings not breaking long lines with breaklines=true and breakatwhitespace=false

Tags: pdftex, listings, verbatim, pandoc

I have the following code in my Markdown:

````
```{latex-fontsize=scriptsize}
    $ ./my-new-application create app_example
    creating app_example
    Generating <path-to-app-src>/new-application/application/config/app_example/application.conf for app_example...
    Application Daemon configuration  written to file: '<path-to-app-src>/new-application/application/config/app_example/application.conf'
    Application Net Name: app_example
    ```
````

This is generated into the following using pandoc:

```
\begin{verbatim}
    $ ./my-new-application create app_example
    creating app_example
    Generating <path-to-app-src>/new-application/application/config/app_example/application.conf for app_example...
    Application Daemon configuration  written to file: '<path-to-app-src>/new-application/application/config/app_example/application.conf'
    Application Net Name: app_example
\end{verbatim}
```

I also have the following in a template.latex file:

```
\definecolor{codegray}{HTML}{F0F0F0}
\definecolor{framegray}{HTML}{C0C0C0}

\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{codegray},
    frame=none,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    autogobble=true,
    columns=fixed,
    basewidth={0.5em,0.5em},
    frame=tblr,
    framextopmargin=4pt,
    framexbottommargin=4pt,
    rulecolor=\color={framegray},
    literate={”}{{''}}1 {“}{{``}}1 {…}{{...}}1 {‒}{{--}}1
}
\let\verbatim\relax
\lstnewenvironment{verbatim}{}{}
```

The resulting output has the line starting with `Generating...` running past the end of the code box.  I need to be able to break this up so that the line wraps on a `/` character.  I've tried a bunch of things and none of them have worked.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution posted by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) in a comment worked, there was an extra equal sign in `rulecolor=\color={framegray},`